# In Pine Script can I detect a line crossover?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a line in Pine Script:

```
baseLine := line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorLower, 0))
```

How can I detect that price has crossed the baseline?

```
isCrossed = ta.crossover(high, baseline)
```

The line above results in following error:

> Cannot call 'ta.crossover' with argument 'source2'='baseline'. An
> argument of 'series line' type was used but a 'series float' is
> expected.

Answer (score 1):

In you example y2 is the end of the line. If your x2 is the bar_index (we can't see because we don't have your entire code), you can use :

```
isCrossed = ta.crossover(high, y2)
```